# How can I connect an android with a local server?

Tags: java, android

sorry if my english isn't perfect.

I'm trying to make an app and I need to exchange information between more devices.

I thought that could be a solution connect the devices on a server but I really don't have the idea where start.

What language I need to study to make this? There is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This highly depends on what you are trying to achieve in the first place. It would be helpful if you could tell what you are trying to do, but I will still outline some general aspects:

1. You need to decide, what information is going to be exchanged and how this should happen

   1. What information: Figure out, what exactly needs to be sent and received. Generic text messages? Images? Byte Streams?
   2. How should this be done: Generally spoken, there are two approaches of getting information as a client: Polling and subscribing.

      - Polling: This approach means to periodically check an endpoint for new data. For example, HTTP uses this way: A web browser or any other client (REST-Client for example) periodically requests information from a HTTP-Server, using a connection just for this single request.
      - Subscribing / Sync / Notification: In some way or another, the client tells the server that it is interested in the information and wants to get notified when there is something new. The connection is initiated at the beginning and held open for further usage. The benefit of this approach is that changes are received immediately, but on the other hand a permanent connection needs to be maintained.
2. Things to study

   - At the beginning, get a good understanding of the TCP/IP Protocol, how Sockets work, how common Protocols do their job (e.g. HTTP, WebSockets)
   - Take a look at specific Protocols working on top of the basic ones

     - Tip: **REST**: Most common WebServices Protocol, providing a common way to exchange stateless data. Uses *Polling*.
     - WebSockets: Socket connection using Web Browsers. Commonly used to update information without needing to poll.
   - There is no specific language to learn for connections. It's more about understanding what the difficulties are and what ways have been invented to address this. Once you get to this point and know what you want to do, it's possible in every language.
   - **Recommendation**: As you seem to use Java/Android, I would try to use REST. A really great client-side library for REST on Android is [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). For the server side use what fits for you .. common Java way would be to use [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/), but you are free to choose from a lot of choices. If using Jersey is too hard for the beginning, maybe take a look at the JS/NodeJS world, those guys invented [Express](http://expressjs.com/de/), which allows you to create a REST service out of just a database, wihtout having to code a lot.

Comment: Hi shorez,thank you for the anwser.

I'm using Java and I'm doing a kind of tombola(a game like Bingo) and I have to comunicate at the device all the lobby that have been created and, once in game, to send all the "moves" of a person to the others.
I have moderate knowleage of java but I always did "offline" programs.
I just need to send Strings and booleans and i think the Subscribing/Sync/Notification will be the best choise in this case.

I will study the "REST" tomorrow, Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @AdSum Hey! In this special case REST isn't the right choice, as it's not a real time protocol. Learning it is essential but don't use it here.
If it's just for simple needs, maybe use a raw socket connection and send json data over it containing the information needed.
Do some research, it's all about choosing the right protocol, important for games are bandwidth and latency!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide if you want to go for an Android or an iOS application. There are other various mobile operating systems as well, but these are widely used . If you want to go for android which is most widely used in my opinion, then you need to learn Java. If you want to go for iOS application, then you need to learn swift or objectiveC. These languages provide the API to connect with various types of services such as Facebook,  Firebase and Amazon etc. If you want to connect to some other local server who’s IP is known to you, then you can use socket programming to send messages.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many ways you can implement this. One way will be using Web services. Of course REST might be a better option, if you follow this approach. You can implement Your service(server side code) with any language. I will recommend you use java since you are already using android.

- Aside from this You might need to go through the basics of REST, its specifications  and
  some reference implementations for language of your preference.